# Apache Rewrite rule is rewriting for /libs even though its exlcuded in the rewriteconditions

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteLog "/private/var/log/apache2/rewrite.log"
    RewriteLogLevel 3
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/etc$  [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/libs$ [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/bin$  [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/home$ [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/var$  [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/content$ [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/siteadmin$
    RewriteRule ^/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/(.*)$  /content/wu/$2_$1/$3 [PT,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Nice config. Did you have a question?

Comment: Do you really have docroot set to the root of your filesystem? Also, check the meaning of "OR"...

Answer (score 3):

Using [OR] with multiple "not" (!) patterns means that every URL will match a RewriteCond.

examples:

- "/foo" matches all of your "RewriteCond" statements and will hit the RewriteRule.
- "/etc" is excluded by the first rule but matches all the others (/etc is not /libs) so it also will hit the RewriteRule.
- same goes for /libs, /bin and the rest you're trying to keep from being requested.

You probably intend to use the default AND behavior.  You want the path to not be /etc AND /libs AND /bin AND /home, etc.